# How can I change a url without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript

I am using ajax to display my contents. As I display my contents, I want to change the browser url dynamically without reloading the page. How can I proceed?

```
window.location.hash="Aboutus";
```

The above code inserts a `#` sign. I do not want a hash sign in my url since my page can contains a similar id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use can use pushState(). Here's some information from Mozilla's developer site:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.c2.a0method

Answer (score 3):

You can use History API that is being introduced in HTML5.  Here is a [link](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) to some examples - you can find links to more resources in the bottom.

Comment: I am getting the Security error" code: "1000..I am using Mozilla 4.0

Answer (score 2):

The HTML5 pushState API should answer your problem.

Comment: I am getting the Security error" code: "1000..I am using Mozilla 4.0

Comment: Try this to check if your browser supports pushState: if (history.pushState) { alert('supported'); }